# How to detect pan gesture in map with Flutter Here SDK

Tags: flutter, here-api

I'm building an app with Flutter and am trying to listen to the pan gestures of the map to get the center of the map view and place a pin on the center. The code I've tried is as follows:

```
void _setPanGestureHandler({HereMapController mapController}) {
    
    _hereMapController.gestures.panListener = PanListener.fromLambdas(
        lambda_onPan: (GestureState gestureState, Point2D panStartPoint,
            Point2D panEndPoint, double panVelocity) {
      if (gestureState == GestureState.begin) {
        print("start pan");
      } else if (gestureState == GestureState.end) {
        var centerPointLat = _hereMapController.viewportSize.width / 2;
        var centerPointLong = _hereMapController.viewportSize.height / 2;
        GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = _hereMapController
            .viewToGeoCoordinates(Point2D(centerPointLat, centerPointLong));
        if (geoCoordinates == null) {
          return;
        }
        _addPoiMapMarker(geoCoordinates);
        _getAddressForCoordinates(geoCoordinates);
      } else if (gestureState == GestureState.update) {
        print("pan updated");
      } else if (gestureState == GestureState.cancel) {
        print("pan cancelled");
      }
    });
  }
```

The code is part of the search_app example and I've just added a panGesture listener to it.

On panning, I get the following in the debug console

```
W/PanGestureDetector(21446): [WARN ] PanGestureDetector - Invalid panning of zero duration but nonzero length, skipping
W/PanGestureDetector(21446): [WARN ] PanGestureDetector - Invalid panning of zero duration but nonzero length, skipping
```

Please let me know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Which package are you using. Add the exact name in your post.

Comment: I'm using the Here Maps SDK for Flutter. It's not a package from pub.dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet from your question is not part of the [search_app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/search_app/lib/SearchExample.dart) example, so I assume it is your code. However, what you are trying to do will not work properly:

- _`hereMapController.viewportSize` is giving you the size in pixels of the map view. It is not providing geographic coordinates. Although you can use `viewToGeoCoordinates()` to convert pixel points to geographic coordinates, there is an easier way: The `MapCamera` gives you always the current center location for free via the [targetCoordinates](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.7.4.0/api_reference/content/mapview/MapCameraState/targetCoordinates.html) property.
- The pan gesture handler is executed multiple times. It would not be advisable  to call `_addPoiMapMarker()` each time the `GestureState.end` event occurs. Instead, you can reposition an existing marker by setting new [coordinates](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.7.4.0/api_reference/content/mapview/MapMarker/coordinates.html).

From your code it looks like you want to get the address of the map view's center. I assume you do not want to recenter a marker each time the map has stopped moving. So, in your case it may be better to draw a fixed widget at the center of your map view, regardless of it's current coordinates - then it will not move or lag behind any events, e.g. you may get from a [MapCameraObserver](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.7.4.0/api_reference/content/mapview/MapCameraObserver-class.html).

The log messages you are receiving are only warnings, so they should not have an effect on the pan gesture event you are receiving.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot find targetCoordinates under MapCamera object. Also, how can I draw a pin statically over the center of the map? Do I use Stack to achieve this? I'm using the Explore edition's SDK

Comment: The targetCoordinates are part of the MapCameraState. _hereMapController.camera.state. targetCoordinates should do the trick. This should work perfectly fine with the Explore Edition. To draw a widget statically over another widget (like the map view) you can use a stack view, yes. It's basically independent of any HERE SDK component.